# Check if Type is Registered in Fixture

Tags: autofixture

I am building a customization for AutoFixture.  I want to register a type/instance with the passed in IFixture, but only if it is not already registered.  Is this possible?

That is, is it possible to check if a particular type/instance is already registered with an AutoFixture IFixture?

The best workaround I have is to try to call fixture.Create() and catch the ObjectCreationException that occurs if the type is not registered.  As you can imagine, that is not the most elegant of solutions, which is why I am asking here for a better one.

Comment: *Is this possible?* Not really... What are you trying to do? In the 6+ years I've used AutoFixture, I don't think I've ever needed that feature...

Comment: OK just making sure.  I am implementing the ITestOutputHelper in xUnit.  To be more specific, I am wanting to output messages that happen during the DataDiscoverer.GetData phase.  The ICustomizer is setting an ILogger interface (acting as a IoC) on the IFixture.  If an ILogger has already been registered with the IFixture, I want to create a CompositeLogger and use that instead.  That way, I am not overwriting any existing registrations/functionality, but moving it into the CompositeLogger.  Hopefully this makes sense. :)  I can check in some code shortly to show you the actual implementation.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up not using a CompositeLogger and [used registrations instead](https://github.com/DragonSpark/Framework/blob/4767b6fcfc1df1df84c30e7e17a6046e2af0326b/DragonSpark.Testing.Framework/OutputCustomization.cs) to get all known loggers within a testing context at the end of a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mark-seemann answered in the comment to the question, this is currently not possible.  The best known solution at the moment is to attempt to [wrap the Fixture's Create call in a try-catch and return null on the ObjectCreationException](https://github.com/DragonSpark/Framework/blob/4767b6fcfc1df1df84c30e7e17a6046e2af0326b/DragonSpark.Testing.Framework/FixtureExtensions.cs#L67-L78).

```
public static T TryCreate<T>( this IFixture @this, Type type )
{
        try
        {
            var result = (T)new SpecimenContext( @this ).Resolve( type );
            return result;
        }
        catch ( ObjectCreationException )
        {
            return default(T);
        }
}
```